# How to represent Dirac matrices in general $n$ dimensions in mathematica?

Tags: matrix, feyncalc

I want to represent Dirac matrices in $N$ dimensions in Mathematica like we have for the Pauli matrices, i.e.

```
PauliMatrix[i], {i,1,3}
```

I guess there must be some kind of package for it, but I cannot find it on the Internet.

Comment: FeynCalc is one package which does this: http://feyncalc.github.io

Comment: To get Dirac matrices in $n$ dimensions like you have for `PauliSigma`, you can use the undocumented built-in function ``Internal`DiracGammaMatrix[i]`` ,  `{i,1,4}`.  Change the option "Metric" to change number of dimensions.

Comment: Change the option "Metric" to change number of dimensions like this: ``Internal`DiracGammaMatrix[10, 
 "Metric" -> {1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}]``.